# Convert image pixels to quadruples

Tags: code-golf, math

Example given an image which width and height is a power of two .

**First step :** Divide each image into Cartesian coordinate quadrants

```
 _____ _____
|     |     |
|  2  |  1  |
|_____|_____|
|     |     |
|  4  |  3  |
|_____|_____|
```

**Second step :**  Divide each quadrant to another four quadrants and add new quadrant id after the old one , like this :

```
 _____ _____ _____ _____
|     |     |     |     |
|  22 |  21 |  12 |  11 |
|_____|_____|_____|_____|
|     |     |     |     |
|  23 |  24 |  13 |  14 |
|_____|_____|_____|_____|
|     |     |     |     |
|  32 |  31 |  42 |  41 |
|_____|_____|_____|_____|
|     |     |     |     |
|  33 |  34 |  43 |  44 |
|_____|_____|_____|_____|
```

**And so on...**

```
 _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
| 222 | 221 | 212 | 211 | 122 | 121 | 112 | 111 |
|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
| 223 | 224 | 213 | 214 | 123 | 124 | 113 | 114 |
|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
| 232 | 231 | 242 | 241 | 132 | 131 | 142 | 141 |
|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
| 233 | 234 | 243 | 244 | 133 | 134 | 143 | 144 |
|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
| 322 | 321 | 312 | 311 | 422 | 421 | 412 | 411 |
|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
| 323 | 324 | 313 | 314 | 423 | 424 | 413 | 414 |
|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
| 332 | 331 | 342 | 341 | 432 | 431 | 442 | 441 |
|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
| 333 | 334 | 343 | 344 | 433 | 434 | 443 | 444 |
|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
```

**Until number of quadrants is equal to the number of pixels**

Should return a 2d array of quadruple coordinates .

Inspired from : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ib88h.jpg

Comment: So what is the input and output?

Comment: Did you mean "power of two" height and width instead of "even" ?

Comment: Suggestion for input: the side length of the image, in pixels.

Comment: What do you mean by "given an image"? Are we given the filename of the image? Or is the binary data of the image piped to the stdin of our program? What is the format of this image (e.g. jpg, png, gif)? If we are to "return a 2d array", does this mean we only have to write a function, not a complete program? P.S. it's "divide", not "devide".

Comment: I don't see the problem you guys have. If input and output aren't clearly specified, you're free to choose what's convenient. The problem itself is clearly specified in my opinion.

Comment: Well i don't think that file format is important , it could also be a Canvas with imageData .. you choose the problem still there .

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, <s>95</s> 86 bytes

Since the method of input has not been specified, I'm simply expecting the resolution to be saved as an integer in the variable `n`

```
r={{""}};Do[r=ArrayFlatten[r/.q_String:>{{q<>"2",q<>"1"},{q<>"3",q<>"4"}}],{Log2@n}];r
```

With indentation:

```
r = {{""}};
Do[
  r = ArrayFlatten[
    r /. q_String :> {{q <> "2", q <> "1"}, {q <> "3", q <> "4"}}
  ],
  {Log2@n}
];
r
```